# Return NULL in case of success

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, null

This question is a clearer version of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931201/return-null-in-case-of-success/46931747#46931747) I posted on SO.

I have a C++ `Planner` object with a method that computes a `Route` from a start point to a destination point. `Planner` is the owner of the computed `Route` pointer.

Now, I have a second method (call it `TestRoute`), that takes the route object and tells if the destination is reachable from the start point, and if not, tries to find a route that passes through fuelling stations.

The original implementation of `TestRoute` was to return a `Route` pointer when the trip is feasible (with or without refuelling), and NULL in case of failure:

- if a refuelling is necessary, `TestRoute` returns a pointer to the new Route;
- if no refuelling is necessary, it returns a pointer to a *copy* of the original Route, since its owner is `Planner`.

In these both cases, it is up to the caller of `TestRoute`to destruct the returned `Route` object.

Well, now, a colleague of mine wants the method returns `NULL` when the route is feasible without refuelling, to avoid useless copy and destruction.

So the method would return:

- NULL in case of failure
- a pointer to a `Route` in case of success when a new `Route` is computed
- NULL in case of success (!!) when no refuelling is necessary.

It sounds to me like a terrible design. May I have some opinion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better to have 2 methods with clear meaning, or just 1 dual use method?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309377/better-to-have-2-methods-with-clear-meaning-or-just-1-dual-use-method)

Comment: And how is the caller supposed to distinguish a total failure from a trivial success?

Comment: @KilianFoth By checking a value of "LastErrorCode"...

Comment: @gnat How is it related to my question?

Comment: it is related in that your and colleagues are both poor design, because of violated CQRS (granted I'm not a big fan of this principle in general but in the context of this specific issue it looks like a great fit)

Comment: Don't know all the details, but maybe what you should do is separate out TestRoute into two methods - one that checks the route (tests if the destination is reachable given a certain amount of fuel), and another that recomputes a new route? Presumably, this recomputation is more expensive then what Planner does? And maybe you could hide all that logic behind something, so that the client code works with a uniform interface.

Comment: On a related note considering design questions and how to improve it, read about classes whose name end with "-er" [here](http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html) and [here](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html), then think about `Planner`...

Comment: Is it feasible just to mutate the original Route* that you pass to TestRoute and have this as a function sig "void TestRoute (Route* r)"? Or is there a reason you need the original route without the fuel points specified?

Comment: There is a reason to keep it in the original form. many field members of Planner depend on the route it has computed

Comment: Rather than splitting/adding more methods why not go the other way and make the original method return a route that already includes tank stops if those are necessary to reach the destination? I don't see why it should be the callers responsibility to make sure the route is feasible.

Comment: Legacy code :) And also because we don't want always this information, and the methode TestRoute (or ComputeRefuellings as it should be called) takes a lot of timer compared to the start->destination route computation

Comment: Have you considered throwing an exception in the event of failure instead of using return/error values?

Comment: You said 'By checking a value of "LastErrorCode"'. If `LastErrorCode` is a function, this is a terrible design. You should avoid requiring callers to call yet another function to see if the previous function succeeded. If it's just a return value, that's far less objectionable.

Answer (score 9):

Returning NULL in case of success (the most simple case for success at that) is definitely contrary to what most people will expect.

Returning a pointer that the user has to manually destruct isn’t super great either. I’d suggest using C++11 `unique_ptr` but using C++11 may not be feasible in your case.

One thought I had is to make `TestRoute` `private` and have the `Planner` call it whenever it computes a new route.

If the test fails, return `NULL`, otherwise return the route.

What’s nice about this approach is that you can implement `TestRoute` however you (or your colleague) please, and the user of the class won’t need to know the details of how it is implemented. The user will just ask for a route from point A to point B and will be guaranteed it’s a valid route with refueling points so long as they don’t receive `NULL`.

You could also split your method into a few different methods if the performance hit isn’t too great.

For example, for `TestRoute`, have it return `true` if the route is possible, `false` if not.

```
bool TestRoute(const Route* r)
```

Have another method `TestRouteNeedRefuel` that returns `true` if the route will require refueling, `false` if not

```
bool TestRouteNeedRefuel(const Route* r)
```

Then have a final method, `GenerateRefuelRoute` that returns a new route with the proper refuel points

```
Route* TestRoute(const Route* r)
//use this if at all possible
std::unique_ptr<Route> TestRoute(const Route* r)
```

As far as performance goes, remember to profile before making assumptions. If your colleague is worried about copying `Route` more than needed (and he may have good reason to, as we don't know how expensive it is or what the target platform is) then clearly performance is an important requirement. I would suggest first implementing as clean an interface as can be done, profiling to find where the bottlenecks REALLY are, and then implementing a few speed hacks where necessary.

Comment: Make TestRoute private and call it by Planner was my first design, but we had to change it due to existing code...

Comment: @Greg82 Ah, that's disappointing. Legacy code... this is why we can't have nice things. If there are any other constraints due to legacy code, you may want to update your question to describe what they are.

Answer (score 8):

I would generally consider returning a pointer from a method in C++ a bad design, and mixing error states and payload data in the return value, too; this is a recipe for unmaintainable code.

Suggested change: Return the fail/success status as int value (or use ternary logic, e. g. [boost::tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/tribool.html)), and pass the argument as non-const reference:

```
/** @returns
    - 1 if a solution has been found. The argument will be updated.
    - 0 if the request has been processed sucessfully, 
      but no (immediate) solution has been found.
      The argument is not modified in this case.
    - -1 if the request failed. The argument is not modified. */
int findSolution(MyClass& argument);
```

Usage example, leaving out premature optimization to avoid "unnecessary" copies:

```
MyClass objectToTest(originalUnmutableObject);

switch(findSolution(objectToTest))
{
    case 1:
        //Replace original with updated object, or whatever
        break;
    case 0:
        //Nothing to do (?)
        break;
    case -1:
        //Error handling
        break;
    default:
        //Unexpected return value
        assert(false);
}
```

An alternative, more sophisticated and reusable approach could be to bundle error state and object into a generic result class; this pattern was inspired by [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/). I leave the implementation of `Result` to you.

```
template<typename T>
class Result
{
    public:
        Result() = delete;
        Result(int error);
        Result(const T& data);
        Result(T&& data);

        //Methods
        bool isOk() const;
        bool isError(int error) const;
        int error() const;
        const T& data() const;

    private:
        //Variables
        int m_error = 0;
        T m_data;
};

...

Result<MyClass> findSolution(const MyClass& argument)
{
    int errorCode = 0;

    ...

    if(errorCode != 0)
        return Result(errorCode);
    else if(solutionFound)
        //Error code of result will be 0, Result::isOk() == true
        return Result(update(argument, solution));
    else
        //Error code of result will be 1, Result::isOk() == false
        return Result(1);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean that the argument is updated if the method returns 0, and not updated if it returns 1? But I cannot *modify* the original object...

Comment: @Greg82 Read the code comments; it's meant vice versa by me; however it's up to **you** to define the meaning of the return values of **your** method. If you can't modify the object then make a copy of it before passing it to the method.

Comment: But the debate was precisely to avoid a useless copy when a solution is found immediately :)

Comment: That seems contradictionary to me; you need to pass a mutable object if you want it to be modified by the method, no matter if you use pointers or references.

Comment: We don't want to *modify* an object. We want to create an updated route if a refuelling is necessary, or keep the original route if it is not. But in latter case, Planner is the owner of the (original route) (and in the former case, the caller is the owner)

Comment: I expanded my example, and I suggest you don't think about premature optimizations (avoiding copies; they are probably cheap in comparison with your route calculations) in favour of read- and maintainable code. Good design first, necessary optimization later.

Comment: How I agree with your last sentence! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid to return raw owning pointer.
You may use smart pointer, and in particularly `shared_ptr`

Assuming:

```
bool NoPath(const Route&);
bool NeedRefuel(const Route&);
std::unique_ptr<Route> RouteWithRefuel(const Route&);
```

you may do:

```
std::shared_ptr<Route> TestRoute(const std::shared_ptr<Route>& r)
{
    if (!r) {
        throw std::runtime_error("null pointer"); // Or more appropriate exception
    }

    if (NoPath(*r)) {
        // throw NoValidPathException{}; // Alternative
        return nullptr; // No valid Path
    } else if (NeedRefuel(*r)) {
        return RouteWithRefuel(*r); 
    } else {
        return r; // share route: Increase ref counting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is a case of barking up the wrong tree.

How about a single function to make everyone happy:

Route PlanRoute(Origin, Destination, FuelRange);

The people who don't care about fuel simply pass in a maximum integer.  If you can't touch the method signature give this version a new name and make the original name just call this one with a maximum integer for the range.

And I can't understand your colleague--how can reallocating a route be remotely as expensive as generating it in the first place?  The only scenario where I can see this making any meaningful difference is if it's being called far more often than the generation (say, checking a fleet of vehicles against the base route) and that could be avoided by modifying the Route object to include the fuel range needed.